# Convert mysql join query to morphia mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, playframework, playframework-1.x, morphia

Currently, we've our application on Play 1.2.5 with MySQL on the backend. We're trying to port this system to MongoDB using Morphia.

We're having problem while converting the MySQL Join Queries to MongoDB that uses Morphia. Following is the SQL query:

```
SELECT jobs.postal, count(distinct timesegments_id), group_concat(timesegments_id order by timesegments_id) as types, latitude, longitude FROM jobs
            left join geocodes on jobs.geocode_id = geocodes.id left join jobs_timesegments on jobs_timesegments.jobs_id = jobs.id
            where geocodes.last_updated is not null
            and longitude >0
            and timesegments_id is not null
            group by jobs.postal;
```

Following is what we tried:

```
List<models.Geocode> Geocodelist = models.Geocode.find().filter("longitude >",0).filter("last_updated",new BasicDBObject("$ne","last_updated")).asList();
    List<String> geocodeids = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (models.Geocode geocode : Geocodelist) {
        geocodeids.add(geocode.getIdAsStr());
    }

    List<models.Job> job = models.Job.find().filter("geocode_id",new BasicDBObject("$in",geocodeids)).asList();

    List<String> jobids = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (models.Job joblist : job) {
        jobids.add(joblist.getIdAsStr());
    }
    List<models.Jobs_TimeSegments> timesegments_data = models.Jobs_TimeSegments.find().filter("jobs_id",new BasicDBObject("$in",jobids)).asList();
```

The above fetches three lists; however, we're not sure how to reference them to each other and get the list of columns that we want.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks